# How to get a shifting windows output on CNN-LSTM time-series forecasting? ([t-120:t] sequence to predict [t+1:t+40])

Tags: machine-learning, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to use CNN+LSTM model for reliable stock price forecasting.
I am hoping to get model pred value of next 40 days output for every day.
I have successfully concatenated the Conv2D layer as LSTM input layer.

In short, **I use [t-120 : t] sequence to predict [t+1 : t+40].**

Now, I faced an issue of model output that prints very similar values (almost constant) during the 60 days of test period.
(It is not exactly the same, but the 40 day trend are almost same)

I am expecting a daily result of 40 days with shifted window.
(see image below for better understanding)

[image]

Here is my question:

1. Why am I getting similar output on my test set? (not shifted window)
2. Is there a problem with my `activation` function (maybe in the `Dense` layer)?

```
def create_model_cnn_lstm(params, numOfFeat, input_shape):
    input_layers = []
    channel_list = []
    
    for i in range(0, numOfFeat):
        layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
        input_layers.append(layer)
 
        layer = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32,(3,3), strides=1,kernel_regularizer=0.01, padding='same', activation="relu", use_bias=True,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))(layer)
        layer = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64,(5,5), strides=1,kernel_regularizer=0.01, padding='same', activation="relu", use_bias=True,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'))(layer)
        layer = TimeDistributed(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2)(layer)
        layer = TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.3))(layer)
        layer = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(layer)
        layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(10))(layer)
        channel_list.append(layer)
    
    layer = Concatenate(axis = -1)(channel_list)
    layer = LSTM(units = 512, activation = 'tanh', return_sequences = False, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.1, kernel_regularizer=0.01)(layer)
    layer = Dense(512, activation = 'tanh')(layer)
    layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)
    layer = Dense(pred_len)(layer)
    model = Model(input_layers, layer)
    
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=params["lr"], beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
    
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'])
    
    return model
```

Comment: Train data size = 455, Validation data size = 132, Test data size = 60

Comment: Do you mean for example you have the same outputs for both input records of [t:t-120] and [t+1:t-119]? Or do you have the same outputs for a single record (40 almost equal outputs)?

Comment: Predicting a sequence (seq2seq) is something that works in the NLP field. It's not surprising that your model converges on constant results because stock markets are quite volatile. You better try just **one-step forecasting** (instead of 40 steps). Or you can predict a trend direction like the way that **open hedge funds** define their targets for their competitions.

Comment: The outputs are [t+1:t+40], but the values are very similar throughout the test set. 
If I try one-step forecasting for 40days, then it sounds like I need 40 models for it, and I was trying to avoid this with seq2seq model. 
Is there any other way?

Comment: You won't need 40 different models. you will build a single one-step forecasting model and call it 40 times to predict your test data. you input [t-120:t] and you predict t+1. then you input [t-119:t+1]  and you predict t+2 ... and so on.

Comment: Well, in that case, how can I get predicted value of t+40 from today where there are no real input data on [t+1:t+39]?
The fact that I need a 40 window period prediction, I was hoping to use Seq2Seq model.

Comment: Plus, if I build a prediction model with a 40days, such as [t-119:t-40] to predict [t+1], the performance were quite not good as a single one-step forecasting model you suggested.
Im in a tight spot here, so any thoughts would help.  :)